# Replacing a conditional with the negative (i.e. using not) causes error with pythons re.sub method

Tags: python, regex, string

I'm trying to replace all characters in a string that windows doesn't like in a file path (such as `%$£^`) with an empty string, using `re.sub`. When I use this:

```
    import string
    import re
    name= '*example -name_with^additional£$characters'
    for j in name:
        if j in string.ascii_letters+string.digits+'_-':
            name=re.sub(j,'',name)
```

The regular expression works and replaces all the characters with an empty string. However, since I want to replace characters NOT in `string.ascii_letters+string.digits+'_-'` i need to use `not` instead...

```
    import string
    import re
    name= '*example -name_with^additional£$characters'
    for j in name:
        if j  not in string.ascii_letters+string.digits+'_-':
            name=re.sub(j,'',name)
```

However, this gives me an error:

```
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\re.py", line 155, in sub
    return _compile(pattern, flags).sub(repl, string, count)

  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\re.py", line 251, in _compile
    raise error, v # invalid expression

error: unexpected end of regular expression
```

Does anybody know what is going on? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue arises because you are trying to `re.sub` with `*` pattern, and it is an invalid regex pattern since you cannot quantify nothing (empty location).

Use a simple `replace`:

```
import string
name= '*example -name_with^additional£$characters'
for j in name:
    if j  not in string.ascii_letters+string.digits+'_-':
        name=name.replace(j,'') # <- here
print(name)
```

See [Python demo](https://ideone.com/4CWyan)

Comment: Note: even [at regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/aV8bW6/1), you can check that the `*` pattern is not valid - *Preceding token is not quantifiable*.

Comment: Ah yes, I see. Thanks